# Union and Intersection of two single linked lists recursively in C without duplicates

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I've tried to write a recursive union function having 2 full lists, but I'm not able to omit the duplicate elements even if I check them, plus the intersection function returns me a empty structure. I think there's definitely an error in isPresent() but I can't detect it.

```
struct list* unione ( struct list* l1, struct list* l2){

    struct list* h1 = l1;
    struct list * h2 = l2;
    struct list* l3 = NULL;
    struct list* tmp = NULL;


    if (h1 != NULL) {
            l3 = push(l3, h1->key);
             l3->next = unione(h1->next, h2);
        }
        tmp = l3;
        if (h2 != NULL){
            int val = h2->key;
            if (!isPresent(tmp, val))
            l3 = unione (h1, h2->next);
            l3 = push (l3, h2->key);
            l3->next = unione (h1, h2->next);


        }

        return l3;
}
```

struct list* intersec ( struct list* l1, struct list* l2){

```
struct list* h1 = l1;
struct list* l3 = NULL;
struct list* h2 = l2;

if (h1 != NULL){
    if (isPresent(l2, h1->key))
        push (l3, h1->key);
    l3 = intersec (h1->next, h2);
}
return l3;
```

}

```
bool isPresent (struct list *head, int elem){
    struct list *tmp = head;
    while (tmp != NULL)
    {
        if (tmp->key == elem)
            return 1;
        tmp  = tmp->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output: (the list2 "11" shouldn't be there) 
List 1:
0->11->4->12->13->3
List 2:
99->11->27
List 3:
99->**11**->27->0->11->4->12->13->3

Intersection:

Comment: Totally unrelated to the question... Yet you should really be consistent with your coding style. This helps you to spot bugs faster and work with a team more easily. Just take a look at all those pointer `*` in your code. :)

Comment: lmao this is not even an answer to my question as you said hahaha I got free() as well in my main() anyways ;)